# Make Website Project location relative

Tags: c#, asp.net, vs-web-site-project

I have just started working on a new web project which is, in fact, a Website project. When I took my own copy of the solution from source control the Website project was still located in another directory.

Is there a way to make a website projects location relative to the solution? I cannot see any references to the physical location in the Solution file (and website projects don't have a project file) Otherwise this is going to be a pain for everyone.

Many thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2):

Is this the kind of website project where the files are actually stored under an IIS mapped folder, code is in the App_Code folder, etc? Do you have to use a project type like that? I think that normal web application projects are a lot better alternative in every way, and they're of course free from this problem, Visual Studio's embedded webserver or IIS express or even regular IIS hosts them in place.

Comment: I agree, I would rather not be using a website project at all. Unfortunately I think I am stuck with it in the short term.